# Why can't I execute other commands while the dialog is running?

Tags: bugs, front-end, evaluation, dialog-window

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier and persisting through 13.1**

> CASE:4226661

---

The code is from the following video:
http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?sx=Ian%20Johnson&v=2076

```
CreateDialog[
    DynamicModule[{
        vals={}
    },
        Column[{
                Dynamic@ListLinePlot[
                    vals=Reverse@Take[Reverse@vals,UpTo[300]],
                    Filling->Axis,
                    AxesLabel->{"Time","Memory (GB)"},
                    Ticks->{None,Automatic},
                    PlotRange->{0,QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[SystemInformation["Machine","PhysicalTotal"],"Gigabytes"]},
                    ImageSize->Medium
                ],
                Dynamic@Refresh[
                    AppendTo[vals,SystemInformation["Machine","PhysicalTotal"]-SystemInformation["Machine","PhysicalUsed"]]//Last,
                    UpdateInterval->1.5
                ]
            },
            Alignment->Center
        ]
    ],
    WindowFloating->True,
    WindowClickSelect->True,
    Modal->False
]
```

In the video the speaker run the above command and then executes the following:

- `x=Range[500000000];2;`
- `ClearAll[x];`

To show how the dialog notes the changes in memory available when storing the expression. But when I run the command it opens the new notebook (dialog) but does not allow me to execute the other command while the dialog is running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bug related to `WindowFloating->True` on Windows. I reported it recently.

Use `WindowFloating->False` or drop it and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

In the recent versions of *Mathematica* evaluating the code in the OP doesn't disable evaluation of the other Notebooks. But the reason is that in these versions the option `WindowFloating->True` applies only to the Notebook windows having `WindowFrame -> "Palette"` (for which it is set to `True` by default):

> `WindowFloating` is really only applicable to palette type frames anymore. Some window managers no longer support arbitrary combinations of frames, floating, etc... With that said, there might come a day when the palette itself is no longer supported. – [ihojnicki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/272375/creating-picture-in-picture-functionality-by-attaching-a-notebook-to-a-notebook/272399#comment680340_272399)

Addition of the option `WindowFrame -> "Palette"` makes the window floating on the top of the other Notebooks and reproduces the problem described in the OP: now you can't evaluate any code in the other Notebooks. Hence the bug is still here.

I reproduce the described behavior with versions 13.1.0, 12.3.1 and 8.0.4 on Windows 10 x64.